# Custom selector like NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Is there any way so that I can change color of icon and text of list item on pressed in My `NavigationDrawer`.

I know I can easily do this with `NavigationView` but my requirement is quite odd so I cannot use `NavigationView`.

Till now I'm able to change color of both after item selection. [image: just like this]

I tried to implement `TouchListener`. but its not working.

**TouchListener**

```
drlyt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // darken background
                imgIcon.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#47ACD6"),
                        Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#47ACD6"));
                Log.e("msg", "Down " + position);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // clear color filter
                imgIcon.setColorFilter(null);
                txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
                Log.e("msg", "Up");
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Please help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: How do you  change color of both after item selection?

Comment: @tinysunlight I have took one static variable and put condition in my adapter if current position is equals to that static variable. if it returns true I set color-filter on icon and set text color to TextView. if it returns false I just simply do wise-versa. and I update that static variable in each Activity to its selected position.

Comment: Yes.. I'm using listview

Answer (score 1):

Support library includes

[AppCompatTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html)

[AppCompatImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html)

which supports [backgroundTint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.attr.html#backgroundTint) and [backgroundTintMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.attr.html#backgroundTintMode). So you can create colorList and using functions like [setSupportBackgroundTintList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView.html#setSupportBackgroundTintList%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29) and [setSupportBackgroundTintMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView.html#setSupportBackgroundTintMode%28android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29).

> yes. and I can find AppCompatTextView but not AppCompatImageView. and
>   can you provide me an exmple that how to use them?

**Using only XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:backgroundTint="@drawable/background"
    app:backgroundTintMode="src_over"/>
```

drawable/background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

**Using only code**

```
 AppCompatImageButton imageButton = (AppCompatImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                        new int[]{}
            },
            new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE}
    ));
    imageButton.setSupportBackgroundTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

Comment: But I'm not using `NavigationView`.

Comment: Check my new answer.

Comment: I can't find that class. I included `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`, but it gives `noClassFoundException`

Comment: Do you add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

Comment: yes. and I can find `AppCompatTextView` but not `AppCompatImageView`. and can you provide me an exmple that how to use them?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its still not working. its seems there is some error in my `AppCompat` library. But thanks for your time and effort.